# PHP Update shows previous database entry's

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-update

I'm currently just coding around in my free time and follow up some random tutorials that other developers/coder's created in there spare time. Now I'm stuck with something very small. I have been trying to find a answer on the interwebz but I cant seem to find one, so here I'm hoping that someone is willing to read my PHP and HTML and see the error I created.

But before I share my code let me tell you what my problem is and what I try to achieve.
If you go to the following link "**removed because problem is solved.**" and when you click on Home/About/Service/Random, you are able to edit one of these menu's. (title, posistion, visible). Now when I want to change the menu name "Home" to "Welcome" it correctly execute my SQL but for some reason, in the HTML Form it loads it's previous information. What I can do is copy the PHP and save it in a new php file and when clicking on submit it will change both menu/title/html form at the same time, but it wont show my succes and fail message anymore. I hope any of you understand what I'm trying to explain here and try to achieve. Now lets share the code.

**PHP**

```
    <? find_selected_page(); ?>

<?
    if (intval($_GET['info']) == 0){
        redirect_to("content.php");
    }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $errors = array();

        $required_fields = array('menu', 'position', 'visible');
        foreach ($required_fields as $fieldname){
            if (!isset($POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) &&
                !is_numeric($_POST[$fieldname]))) {
                $errors [] = $fieldname;
            }
        }

        $fields_with_lengths = array('menu' => 30);
        foreach($fields_with_lengths as $fieldname => $maxlength) {
            if(strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) > $maxlength){
                $errors[] = $fieldname;
            }
        }

    $id = mysql_prep($_GET['info']);
    $menu = mysql_prep($_POST['menu']); //use post array cuz we used post var to coll val in form
    $position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
    $visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);

        $query = "UPDATE information SET menu = '{$menu}', position = {$position}, visible = {$visible} WHERE id = {$id}";

            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
                if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
                    $message = "The information was correctly updated."; 
                } else {
                        //failed

                }

             } else { //errors 

         }

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<? require_once ("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<? require_once ("includes/connect.php"); ?> //HERE IS MY CONNECTION TO MY DATABASE

///HERE IS MY PHP CODE

<? include ("includes/header.php"); ?>

    <div id="content"> <!-- content here -->

        <table id="table">
                <tr>
                    <td id="nav">
                        <? echo navigation($sel_table1, $table2); ?>

                    </td>
                <td id="main">
                    <h2>Edit Info <? echo $sel_table1['menu']; ?></h2>


                    <? if (!empty($message)) { echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>

                    <form action="edit_info.php?info=<? echo urlencode($sel_table1['id']); ?>" method="post"/>
                        <p>Menu title
                            <input type="text" name="menu" value="<? echo ($sel_table1['menu']); ?>" id="menu">
                        </p>
                        <p>Position
                            <select name="position">

                                <?

                                $info_set = get_all_info();
                                $info_count = mysql_num_rows($info_set); //asks how many rows there are should be 3
                                for($count=1; $count <= $info_count+1; $count++){
                                    echo "<option value='{$count}'";
                                        if($sel_table1['position'] == $count){
                                            echo "selected";
                                        }
                                        echo ">{$count}</option>";
                                }

                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                        <p>Visible:
                            <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" 
                                <? if ($sel_table1['visible'] == 0){ echo "checked"; } ?>
                            />No
                            &nbsp;
                            <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" 
                                <? if ($sel_table1['visible'] == 1){ echo "checked"; } ?>
                            />Yes
                        </p>
                            <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Edit information" />
                        </form> <br>

                        <a href="content.php">Cancel</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<? include ("includes/footer.php");?> //HERE I HAVE IF ISSET MYSQL CLOSE
```

And a more simple short version of the story is, I want to update the menu's with the success and failure message's without getting the old previous data in my HTML FORM

**if needed for any reasons I have included the part of my functions.php where $sel_table and $table2 are staying.**

```
function find_selected_page(){

    global $sel_table1;
    global $table2;

    if (isset($_GET['info'])){
        $sel_table1 = get_info_by_id($_GET['info']);
        $sel_t2 = 0;
        $table2 = NULL;
}   else if (isset($_GET['page'])){
        $table1 = 0;
        $sel_table1 = NULL;
        $table2 = get_pages_by_id($_GET['page']);
}   else {
        $table1 = NULL;
        $sel_table1 = NULL;
        $table2 = 0;
    }
}

function navigation($sel_table1, $table2){
    $output = "<ul class='info'>";
        $info_set = get_all_info();
            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($info_set))
        {
            $output .= "<li"; if ($info["id"] == $sel_table1 ["id"]){
                $output .= " class='selected'";
            }

            $output .= "><a href='edit_info.php?info=" . urlencode($info["id"]) . "'>{$info['menu']}</a></li>"; 
                $page_set = get_pages_for_info($info["id"]);

            $output .= "<ul class='pages'>";
                while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set))
            {
                $output .= "<li"; if ($page["id"] == $table2 ["id"]){
                    $output .= " class='selected'";
            }
                $output .= "><a href='content.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) . "'>{$page['menu']}</a></li>"; }
                    $output .= "</ul>";
            }
                    $output .= "</ul>";
                    return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Where $sel_table1['menu'] is defined ?

Comment: So it's normal, you getting the value BEFORE processing SQL update. You should change that : replace the value of the array with the update value. :)

Comment: @Spoke44 let me try that out. If in anycase the values are needed to better understand my code, I have edited the original posted with the part where $sel_table and its relation is included.

Comment: @Spoke44 Thanks for the tip/info, or whatever I shall call it. It works like a charm now, I would like to vote your comment as an answer, but I don't know how to, and I cant find the vote as answer button. So yeahh sorry about that, but again thanks for the help.